# Test private function in leaflet plugin for drawing overlay (karma/jasmine)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, leaflet, karma-jasmine

So this question differs from all the other "how do I test private functions" questions in that it's a leaflet plugin, so it has no public methods, and it doesn't return the result of the constructor.

What I'm working on is roughly based on [Leaflet.Grid](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.Grid), a leaflet plugin to put latitude/longitude lines on a leaflet map.

So how would you go about testing a function such as [Leaflet.Grid's `_dec2dms`](https://github.com/jieter/Leaflet.Grid/blob/d0c3ea9151e83fd13501a21aabe0d945a1f43770/L.Grid.js#L184)?

It's a function that isn't exposed, but is doing math that could have a test. (In my plugin, I have a few functions that do complex math, and I need them to be tested as I've already seen a few edge cases)

Would you just move it outside the plugin, and change `this._dec2dms` to `_dec2dms`, or would you just mock Leaflet entirely?

I'm leaning towards providing a mock Leaflet, and testing through that but I'm hopeful there is a simpler way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaflet maintainer here.

What you are describing looks pretty close to the [unit tests of `Leaflet.Draw`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/tree/master/spec).

In those tests (in the [Karma configuration](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw/blob/master/spec/karma.conf.js), to be precise), the most current Leaflet files are included.

From my point of view, it's a good practice to include the original library when you're developing tests for a plugin. This will ensure that the plugin is compatible with the library, and not just with a mock. Also, this will make it easier to see the tests fail when updating the library in case a new version introduces a breaking change.

Comment: So to confirm, you're recommending putting the helper functions inside `L`, such as `L.LatLngUtil` in `Leaflet.Draw`, so you can test them directly, and then also having tests of instantiating the plugin, and checking testable behaviors in leaflet? Isn't that polluting the `L` namespace?

Comment: Yes, that's an accepted solution right now. Until we implement a better solution (ES6 modules) we feel that plugins putting more things in the `L` namespace is fine, as long as it's properly under control.